# Download Archive File in ios Safari with javascript. The filename is not set

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I'm building a javascript code to dowload a zip file in ios Safari. I'm using the FileReader object to do this.
My code is:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(evt) {                 
 window.open(evt.target.result.replace("data:","data:application/zip"),'_blank');
};
var file = new File([streamfile], 'fileName', {type: 'application/zip'});
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

In Safari after download the file in iPad, the archive haven't the name:

[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55370821/ios-safari-issue-of-download-file-name-is-unknown