# IOS Safari issue of download file name is "Unknown"

Tags: ios, reactjs, download, axios

I implemented a Jersey REST service to download the zip file.
Now, I would like to use axios in front end to download the zip file.
Everything is fine in PC Chrome but when tried with Safari on iPad it opens a tab with name "unknown".

I have searched some articles and mentioned that this may related to IOS safari compatibility.
e.g. https://caniuse.com/#feat=download

However, I also want know if there is any method to show the downloaded file as "file.zip" for safari.

Below is my code

Backend:

```
@GET
@Path("/getTestingReport")
@Produces("application/zip")
public Response getTestingReport() throws Exception {
    // set file (and path) to be download
    File file = new File("C:/Users/abc/Desktop/test.zip");

    ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok((Object) file);
    responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"MyJerseyZipFile.zip\"");
    return responseBuilder.build();         
}
```

Frontend:

```
 axios.get("report/getTestingReport").then((response) => {
    console.log("response", response)

    var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/zip" });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'file.zip');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error("error response", error.response)
});
```

May I have any suggestion?